# Warning: Prop `id` did not match. using tinymce with next js

Tags: tinymce, next.js

hi i'm using tinymce for react from this doc [TinyMCE Doc link](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/)

and it works but i get this warning from console

[image: warning screenshot]

im using "next": "^8.0.1", and  @tinymce/tinymce-react": "^3.0.1"

so why this happen? anyone can help me? thanks

Comment: Looks like your issue has to do with server side rendering returning different HTML than what the client expects. Are you using some SSR framework like Gatsby or Next.js?

Comment: yes im using next js

Comment: Got it. See my full answer posted below. Let me know how that goes.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54850634/warning-prop-id-did-not-match-using-tinymce-with-next-js/54853340#54853340

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing as you're using `Next.js`, this issue usually happens when you're initializing something in your `render` method or Functional Component function body that should properly belong in a lifecycle handler.

If you don't have a particular reason to server-render TinyMCE, you can try to do it on the client side only.

Try moving some of the code that initializes TinyMCE in your `componentDidMount` or `useEffect` Hook (depending on whether you're using a Class Component or Functional Component with Hooks).

This will both avoid the SSR vs browser mismatch issues and ease the load on your server.

Comment: You can also ask this question on their official GitHub discussions page: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions

Answer (score 5):

I still face this problem using nextjs v9.x.x with @tinymce/tinymce-react v3.8.1.

The easy way is to add a fixed `id` prop to the `Editor` component like this:

```
<Editor id="YOUR_FIXED_ID" init={{...tiny_mce_options}} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Now in 2020, it possible to use dynamic import in Next.js. With *ssr: false* option.

[Official Doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import)

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me. Here is complete code for editor:

```
<Editor
    id='FIXED_ID'
    apiKey="my-api-key"
    onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor}
    initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor.</p>"
    init={{
        height: 500,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
            'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
            'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
            'removeformat | help',
        content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
    }}
/>
```